# The difference in space octal/hex vs. ascii takes up in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, hex, ascii, octal

So the letter `a` in decimal is `97`, in hex is `61`, and in octal is `141`. You can write it like this in JavaScript:

```
var octal = [ '\141', '\141', '\141' ]
var hex   = [ '\x61', '\x61', '\x61' ]
var ascii = [ 'a', 'a', 'a' ]
```

They all result in the same thing:

```
console.log(octal) //=> ["a", "a", "a"]
console.log(hex)   //=> ["a", "a", "a"]
console.log(ascii) //=> ["a", "a", "a"]
```

However, the first part I'm wondering about is, they are the actually different amount of ASCII characters *to define*:

```
'\141' (4)
'\x61' (4)
'a'    (1)
```

I am wondering if you define a big block of text in octal or hex, it will actually take up 4x the amount of space in the file. So if you returned a JSON response from `/api/resources.json` as octal, the response would be 4x the size of if you returned ASCII. That is, a response to this:

```
'\141\141\141\141\141\141\141\141\141\141\141\141....'
```

Versus a response to this:

```
'aaaaaaaaaaa....'
```

So I'm not sure if it's actually making the file size/response size bigger (probably a dumb question but this [encoding stuff](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes) is difficult). Just want to make sure that, yes, it will take up more space, because that's what it seems like. So basically, writing "raw hex/octal" in a JavaScript file causes it to get bigger more than ASCII.

Comment: Since a JSON response is a string and octal or hexadecimal is invalid in JSON, you will have to send those values as strings as well. So yes, it seems very logical to me that if you have to describe each character as a string of 4 characters, the file will be about 4 times bigger. It's only when you parse the string back to a String object, that it might get stored more efficiently under the hood. But before then, the script won't know the string is octal or hexadecimal.

Comment: Your observation is correct, and forms part of the difference between compiled and interpreted languages. In a compiled language, the resulting object code would be the same, the only size difference is in the source code. At this end of the scale (ie specifying a single character), the overhead isn't that big, but if you are defining a lot of text this way, or doing something like encoding a binary image file in an ASCII format (such as URL Encoding), then the data used become significant, impacting page load times

Comment: In principle, yes. If you're passing data using an encoding that takes more bytes to represent the same data it will be larger however given your example if you created a simple node server with express and returned a string as the result, the string would be encoded the same way regardless of how you express it in your js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`js` files store text, the more you write the bigger the file size gets.

This isn't an issue for compiled languages since the source code's purpose is to produce some other language (Intermediate language, byte code etc.) where syntax semantics are rationalised.

`javascript` files written for the purpose of browsers aren't compiled before being distributed so the file size can be a factor to consider in terms of performance.

So it really depends what your writing `javascript` for...

If you're writing it for your `NodeJs` run-time environment the performance difference will be negligible.

If you're serving `js` files from a web server with large strings defined using hex character notation you could decrease you loading times a bit.